# How to create a working directory using mkdir command in Mac OS X?

Tags: python, shell, directory

I started learning python recently and I am very new to programming.

My book tells the following :

> On Unix-based systems (including Mac OS X and Linux), your working directory might be in /usr/home and be created by a mkdir command in a shell window or file explorer GUI specific to your platform, but the same concepts apply. The Cyg- win Unix-like system for Windows is similar too, though your directory names may vary (/home and /cygdrive/c are candidates).

I am running python on a Mac OS X and I am finding hard to create a directory.

What code should I type in the Terminal ?

I tried :

1. mkdir

It says :usage: mkdir [-pv] [-m mode] directory ...

2. cd c: mkdir

It outputs : -bash: cd: c:: No such file or directory

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: `mkdir mydir` creates a directory called `mydir` then you could change directory like `cd mydir`. To get further information you could check out the man page for `mkdir` using `man mkdir` from your terminal. I'm not really sure what you mean with `working directory`, The `pwd` command prints out the current working directory ie the directory you are currently standing in.

Comment: @Cyclone I tried it. It outputs nothing :) Did  I do it correct ? I made a directory called mkdir mywork..... Thank You so much

Comment: If you stand in your home folder and execute `mkdir mydir` this should create a directory called `mydir` under your home directory (it should not output anything to the terminal), then you simply may change the working directory to `mydir` using `cd mydir`. Notice that `cd` stands for change directory.

Comment: @Cyclone what are we changing mydir to in the second command "cd mkdir" ?

Comment: @Cyclone after executing mkdir mywork. I executed pwd, and it printed /Users/myname

Comment: Like I said to change the current working directory you must step into it `cd mywork`. You can also list the contents of a folder using the `ls` command.

Comment: You're welcome. You might wan't to read up on some basic and useful commands: [Basic Introduction To Unix Commands](http://www.iafe.uba.ar/u/dario/computation/unix/intro.html) and [Introduction To Unix Commands](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afsk)

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir mydir` creates a directory called `mydir`; then you could change directory like `cd mydir`. To get further information you could check out the man page for `mkdir` using `man mkdir` from your terminal. I'm not really sure what you mean with *working directory*. The `pwd` command prints out the current working directory, i. e. the directory you are currently standing in. –  Cyclone

Answer (score 1):

For making directory in mac use below command:

> mkdir nameOfDir

If you want to check directory then use below command:

> cd nameOfDir

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the name you want to use for your directory. If the name contains any characters as '#', '$' etc., then it might be considered as another command in the bash. Try to name your directory using only lowercase alphabets and underscores because of its convention(at least as far as I know).

If you want to still name it using some unconventional characters then use '' to tell the machine that it should not be considered as a command. It might look something like this.

```
$ mkdir \#659div2
```

Here character '#' is the unconventional character. Or like this

```
$ mkdir images\ from\ tour
```

Here character ' '(space) is an unconventional character.

Comment: I guess in your question working directory has no significance. This is true for making any new directory.